# Can we stun without dealing damage?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill, betrayal-widows-walk

In survival guide for Haunt #58 it is written: You cannot deal damage to the traitor. Does that mean we can't even stun the traitor? Maybe not because attacking to stun works only on monsters.

What are all the ways this particular traitor's movement can be hindered (apart from the standard "stand in the same room as an obstacle")? Looking for answers from the second and third editions and Widow's Walk expansion.